# Words Inside The Character Class

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

In a character class can I match full words?

Using this code, the regular expression removes the `{else}` tag, so is it possible to add `else` inside of the character class as a word, and not as 4 letters?

```
$section = "
{if {money} == 'yes'}
   Sweet!
{else}
    Too bad...
{/if}
";

echo preg_replace("/\{[^ \/]+\}/iU", "''", $section);
```

I thought that this might work (but it doesn't):

```
echo preg_replace("/\{[^ (else)\/]+\}/iU", "''", $section);
```

Expected output:

```
{if '' == 'yes'}
   Sweet!
{else}
    Too bad...
{/if}
```

Comment: I updated the question with what I have tried

Comment: *"In a character class can I match full words?"* No, it's a **character** class, as in **single character**

Comment: What's the result you're expecting?

Comment: no you can't. besides nested constructs's will make most regexes difficult to implement/maintain, even with recursion `(?R)`. a simple parser would be better imo

Comment: I would basically like to remove all `{.+?}` items unless there is a space within it.

Comment: @RyanNaddy Answering your first question: no, in a character class you can't match full words. You could just use a (non-)capturing group as in `(?:if|else)` to match either `if` or `else`

Comment: Write the output of what your expecting!

Comment: What does the modifier `U` do, I've never seen that before, doesn't seem to be in the manual?

Comment: `U` = PCRE_UNGREEDY  it is basically the same as doing `.+?` with the `U` I can do `.+` instead

Comment: @php_nub_qq Match ungreedy. For example `/.*?/` is the same as `/.*/U`. Honestly, I don't like to use it since it gets complicated with big patterns. Explicitly writing laziness is much cleaner and clear IMO

Comment: Okay so why don't you just put a space or a slash in your `{else}`? For example `{ else }` would actually even look good?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**. You absolutely can not place words inside of a character class `[]`.

But you can use a **Negative Lookahead** here instead.

```
$section = <<<DATA
{if {money} == 'yes'}
   Sweet!
{else}
    Too bad...
{/if}
DATA;

$section = preg_replace('~\{(?!else|/)\S+\}~i', "''", $section);
echo $section;
```

See [`Live demo`](https://eval.in/82293)

Regular expression:

```
\{            '{'
 (?!          look ahead to see if there is not:
  else        'else'
  |           OR
  /           '/'
 )            end of look-ahead
  \S+         non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)
\}            '}'
```

Comment: Awesome! I love your explanation! I never really understood look ahead till now!

Comment: Maybe this will come in handy. [How to use Lookaheads and Lookbehinds in your Regular Expressions](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/how-to-use-lookaheads-and-lookbehinds-in-your-regular-expressions/)